# SQL Server saves decimal(18,2) as 0,00 instead of 0.00

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I upgraded SQL Server version from 2012 to 2014 and for some reasons, the data is saved as 0,00 instead of 0.00. Please advise as it wasn't happening in SQL Server 2012

[image: SQL results]

Comment: SQL Server neither stores the `,` nor the `.` - it's your SQL client (the application where you run your SQL statements) that _formats_ the numbers like that when displaying them. So which SQL client are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I suspect it's a language setting then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **Control Panel**, then click on **Region** (if your View by is Large/Small Icons), otherwise, click on **Clock & Region**, then click on **Region**.

When that is opened, click on **Additional Settings**.

Navigate to the **Decimal Symbol** row as can be seen below:

[image]

Set the **Decimal Symbol** to `.`, then navigate to the **Currency Tab** and do the same for **Decimal Symbol**.

Click on Apply & OK, then Apply & OK.

That should resolve it.